# Can SharePoint be installed by simply copying files?

Tags: sharepoint, installation

I have a SharePoint website I need to move to another completely different server.
Can I do this by simply copying files from IIS to the other server's IIS folder?
I assume I need to copy the database as well as change the config file's database connection.

I assume I don't need to install anything on the server other than ftp files across i.e. I don't need to install files via an installer or exe.

Comment: Not being funny, but how many applications do you have on windows that can be installed 'by copying files'?

Comment: That's exactly why I asked the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no.

SharePoint includes Service applications (ex. OWSTimer) that have to be registered and installed.

Also there are COM components that must be registered properly.